# XDebug like tool for Elixir

Tags: elixir

I come from PHP background to Elixir and am a great fan of [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) with all its options to view stack trace with values passed to functions/methods during runtime.

Is there a similar tool in Elixir that I can use to watch the values of variables?  I know IEx.pry is an option, but I'd like to know if a debugger similar to XDebug is available - which is enabled through a configuration switch, as I'd like to do this for code that's not in my control.  (e.g. errors that I faced during `mix local.hex`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what XDebug does but there are some options for debugging Elixir/Erlang code:

Observer: http://erlang.org/doc/man/observer.html  (from within iex, type `:observer.start` to start it.

Debugger: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/debugger/debugger_chapter.html (from within iex, type `:debugger.start` to start it.

Try those two tools and see if they answer your need.